# Как вставить значение в список списка на заданный индекс?

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется список

```
re_list = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

Нужно чтобы `re_list[0][0]`, был допустим `8`, а остальные списки чтобы остались как есть.

Пробовал `re_list[0].insert(0,8)`, но не вышло.

Comment: Вам что-то мешает просто присвоить нужное значение `re_list[0][0] = 8`?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вы чуть-чуть не дошли до решения, вам надо не re_list[0], а re_list:

```
>>> re_list = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
>>> re_list.insert(0, [8])
>>> re_list
[[8], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

Либо если вам надо поменять значение, то:

```
>>> re_list = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
>>> re_list[0][0] = 8
>>> re_list
[[8], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```